# filtering the autocomplete data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

My scenario is I bring some values as `autocomplete` from database which is as `V001/Vendor 1`, `V002/Vendor 2`, .....

SO what I want is if User already selected `V001/Vendor 1` in first textbox then he should not be able to select the same `V001/Vendor 2` in second textbox. Here is how it looks like

[image: Vendor]

Also, see my autocomplete code which is in jquery

```
autocompleteOptions = {
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = $.trim(request.term);
        $.ajax({
            //receives json array answer from the url
            url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "App/GetVendorList",
            data: { "VENDORNAME": "" + extractLast(term) + "" },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var datalist = JSON.parse(data);
                response($.map(datalist, function (element, index) {
                    return {
                        label: element.VENDORNAME,
                        value: element.VENDORCODE + "/" + element.VENDORNAME
                    };
                }));
            },
            error: function () {
                // added an error handler
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    ["VENDORNAME", "VENDORCODE"]
                    , extractLast(term)));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, u) {
        if (u.item.value == "") {
            return false;
        }
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val((ui.item ? ui.item.value : ""));        
        if ($(this).val().trim() == "" || $(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == "null") {
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            var id = parseInt(name.substr(13, name.length));
            $('#spFromDate' + id).val('');
            $('#spToDate' + id).val('');
        }
    },

};

$("#txtVendorName1").autocomplete(autocompleteOptions);
```

Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Maintain an array of all the selected text. And then while displaying autocomplete values remove those items.

Comment: @Lalit: how to do that, any link where it has been done ?

Comment: You have two textboxes that are using the autocomplete. But in your code you are displaying only one `$("#txtVendorName1").autocomplete(autocompleteOptions);`. Where is the second one?

Comment: @edkeveked: the second one is generated dynamically whenever user needs it. he can generate upto 5 textboxes.

Comment: Do you need to filter regarding all the texboxes or only the first one ?

Comment: @edkeveked: yes filter for all textboxes.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by removing in the second autocomplete what has been previously selected. You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the datalist before returning to the autocomplete.

So first you use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to push all elements that have been already selected in the array `alreadySelected`.

```
var alreadySelecte = [];
....

$('[id^=txtVendorName]').each(function(){
   alreadySelected.push($(this).val());
})
```

And using this array, you can filter your others auto complete

```
datalist = datalist.filter( item => !alreadySelected.includes(`${item.VENDORCODE}/${item.VENDORNAME}`))
```

Because this is the value : `value: element.VENDORCODE + "/" + element.VENDORNAME` you are setting for each autocomplete input

Comment: I didn't got you, what exactly did u changed here and does it worked ?

Comment: @VVVV, I used a filter after getting the `datalist`

Comment: @VVVV, Can you please post here or edit your question with the output of `console.log(datalist)` and `console.log($("#txtVendorName1").val())` ?

Comment: i am getting syntax error at this line ` datalist = datalist.filter( item => !alreadySelected.includes(item.VENDORNAME))` here `item =>`

Comment: it’s highlighting as red in the js file.

Comment: @VVVV It is not an issue; maybe you are using a javaScript linter that does not accept the arrow function or something like that. If that is the case, try to change the arrow function, by an ES5 syntax `filter(function(item){return!alreadySelected.includes(item.VENDORNAME) })`

Comment: still getting error at `item.VENDORNAME` error as `Expected )`

Comment: If you rewrite as follow, there should not be any error: 
`datalist = datalist.filter(function(item){return !alreadySelected.includes(item.VENDORNAME) })`; If you have some errors, try to see if you don't have some trailing parenthesis or brackets in your code

Comment: can u come over chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162328/jquery-discussion

Comment: after so much of discussion on chat, finally ur answer worked for me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear second textbox value on select option from autocomplete suggation if textbox2 has same value with textbox1 , this way user is unable to select same option again.

Try this type code :

```
$(document).on('change','#textbox2',function(){
   var value1=$('#textbox1').val();
   var value2=$('#textbox2').val();
   if(value2==value1){
    $('#textbox2').val("");
   }
});
```